# How to make new weight parameter in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

In this SS_wrapper class, I have to calculate new weight parameter.

In the `reset_weights(self)` function, I created a new weight (weight to be used in the backward) via `torch.nn.init.uniform_(self.fixed_fb_weights)`. But, I don't know how to do this with forward weight sign and multiplication. I'm curious how to make `self.sign * self.fixed_fb_weights` do by putting them inside `self.fixed_fb_weights` and worked.

Now, the result of multiplying the sign is not shown in `self.fixed_fb_weights`, but only `torch.nn.init.uniform_`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I create a new function and parameter.
In init function, I added `self.feedbak_weight = nn.Parameter(self.sign_weights())` under `self.reset_weights()`.
and new function `sign_weights()` is

```
    def sign_weights(self):
        return self.sign*self.fixed_fb_weights
        #print('sign_weights result : ', self.fixed_fb_weights)
```

and SS_hook_pre function, it returns `self.feedback_weight`.

```
def SS_hook_pre(self, grad):
        if self.output_grad is not None:
            if (self.layer_type == "fc"):
                return self.output_grad.mm(self.feedback_weight)
                #return self.output_grad.mm(self.w)
            elif (self.layer_type == "conv"):
                
                return torch.nn.grad.conv2d_input(self.x_shape, self.feedback_weight, self.output_grad, self.stride, self.padding)
                
            else:
                raise NameError("=== ERROR: layer type " + str(self.layer_type) + " is not supported in FA wrapper")
        else:
            return grad
```